# PrestaShop 1.6.1.9 - Cannot disable Cart block Ajax

Tags: ajax, prestashop-1.6

I am trying to disable the hover functionality on the default Cart block module on PrestaShop.

I have disabled the Ajax cart via Modules & Services > Cart block > Configure but for some reason it does not work?

Has anyone had this problem in the past and if so, how do I fix it?

Comment: The AJAX setting is for whether putting new products into the cart is going to reload the page, or update the cart via AJAX. What the cart does when you hover over it, has nothing to do with that - that is the theme’s responsibility.

Comment: @CBroe, thank you for explaining. Do you know how I would disable the hover functionality?

Comment: If your theme doesn’t offer that as a separate setting, then you will have to modify it accordingly. Might perhaps be enough to remove a bit of CSS or JavaScript, but depends on the specific theme.